# Component Gateway with DataprocOperator on Airflow

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-dataproc

In GCP it is fairly simply to install and run a [JupyterHub component](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials/jupyter-notebook) from the UI or the gcloud command. I'm trying to script the processus through Airflow and the [DataprocClusterCreateOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/dataproc_operator/index.html?highlight=dataproc#airflow.contrib.operators.dataproc_operator.DataprocClusterCreateOperator), here an extract of the DAG

```
from airflow.contrib.operators import dataproc_operator  

create_cluster=dataproc_operator.DataprocClusterCreateOperator(
        task_id='create-' + CLUSTER_NAME, 
        cluster_name=CLUSTER_NAME,
        project_id=PROJECT_ID,
        num_workers=3,
        num_masters=1,
        master_machine_type='n1-standard-2',
        worker_machine_type='n1-standard-2',
        master_disk_size=100,
        worker_disk_size=100,
        storage_bucket='test-dataproc-jupyter', 
        region='europe-west4', 
        zone='europe-west4-a',
        auto_delete_ttl=21600, 
        optional_components=['JUPYTER', 'ANACONDA']
    )
```

However I can not managed to specifify the needed `enable-component-gateway` parameter. Looking at the source code, it seems the parameters is not intended (both in the [deprecated](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/operators/dataproc_operator.py) or the  [last stable](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/dataproc.py) operator).

I know the REST API provides the `endpointConfig.enableHttpPortAccess`, but I would rather use the official operator. 
Does anyone has an idea how to achieved that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Edit, a fix fit for composer-1.8.3 with airflow-1.10.3**

In Airflow 1.10.3, the cluster configuration cannot be externally created. However we can inherit the cluster creation operator and override the configuration creation. This will also let us to set the optional components, a parameter missing from this Airflow's version.

```py
class CustomDataprocClusterCreateOperator(DataprocClusterCreateOperator):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomDataprocClusterCreateOperator, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def _build_cluster_data(self):
        cluster_data = super(CustomDataprocClusterCreateOperator, self)._build_cluster_data()
        cluster_data['config']['endpointConfig'] = {
            'enableHttpPortAccess': True
        }
        cluster_data['config']['softwareConfig']['optionalComponents'] = [ 'JUPYTER', 'ANACONDA' ]
        return cluster_data

#Start DataProc Cluster
dataproc_cluster = CustomDataprocClusterCreateOperator(
    task_id='create-' + CLUSTER_NAME, 
    cluster_name=CLUSTER_NAME,
    project_id=PROJECT_ID,
    num_workers=3,
    num_masters=1,
    master_machine_type='n1-standard-2',
    worker_machine_type='n1-standard-2',
    master_disk_size=100,
    worker_disk_size=100,
    storage_bucket='test-dataproc-jupyter', 
    region='europe-west4', 
    zone='europe-west4-a',
    auto_delete_ttl=21600, 
    dag=dag
)
```

**Original answer, for Airflow 1.10.7**

While not optimal, you can create the Cluster data structure yourself instead of having Airflow's ClusterGenerator to do that. It should work on the latest version (1.10.7)

```py
cluster = {
  'clusterName': CLUSTER_NAME,
  'config': {
    'gceClusterConfig': {
      'zoneUri': 'europe-west4-a'
    },
    'masterConfig': {
      'numInstances': 1,
      'machineTypeUri': 'n1-standard-2',
      'diskConfig': {
        'bootDiskSizeGb': 100
      },
    },
    'workerConfig': {
      'numInstances': 3,
      'machineTypeUri': 'n1-standard-2',
      'diskConfig': {
        'bootDiskSizeGb': 100
      },
    },
    'softwareConfig': {
      'optionalComponents': [
        'ANACONDA',
        'JUPYTER'
      ]
    },
    'lifestyleConfig': {
      'autoDeleteTtl': 21600
    },
    'endpointConfig': {
      'enableHttpPortAccess': True
    }
  },
  'projectId': PROJECT_ID
}
#Start DataProc Cluster
dataproc_cluster = DataprocClusterCreateOperator(
    task_id='create-' + CLUSTER_NAME,
    project_id=PROJECT_ID,
    num_workers=3,
    region='europe-west4', 
    zone='europe-west4-a',
    cluster = cluster,
    dag=DAG
)
```

In case you are using another Airflow version, please specify that.

You can also vote for the bug I've opened: [AIRFLOW-6432](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-6432)

Comment: I am using `composer-1.8.3` with `airflow-1.10.3`, it seems I cannot update to `1.10.7` (yet?), I am also using `airflow.contrib.operators.dataproc_operator` since I cannot access the other operator. The cluster is created with your work around but it seems that the `endpointConfig.enableHttpPortAccess`is not taking in account (I see in the UI that  the Component gateway is still disabled)

Comment: Hi @kwn, please see the revised answer

Comment: Thanks David it works like a charm! Is there anyway to get the resulting Jupyter URL address though? (How to set a fix one?)

Comment: going to the GCP console (https://console.cloud.google.com/dataproc/clusters), find your cluster, and then you can find the link to jupyter under the "Web Interfaces" tab. Notice that clusters can fail at some point, and that the new one can have a new URL. Perhaps you can have a cloud function tied to an http endpoint, that will find the cluster using its name, take the jupyter url from its metadata (use dataproc.get_cluster) and then redirect to that URL.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I knew for the "Web interfaces" tab, I am looking for a more automatic way so I will dig into your second point.

Answer (score 1):

David answer is correct for older Airflow versions however for Airflow>=2.0.0 there is now easier way using `ClusterGenerator`. This means there is no need to create custom operator:

```
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.dataproc import ClusterGenerator, DataprocCreateClusterOperator

CLUSTER_GENERATOR = ClusterGenerator(
    project_id=PROJECT_ID,
    region=REGION,
    ...,
    enable_component_gateway=True,
    optional_components = [ 'JUPYTER', 'ANACONDA' ]
).make()

DataprocCreateClusterOperator(
    ...,
    cluster_config=CLUSTER_GENERATOR
)
```

You can check this [example dag](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/b2c0a921c155e82d1140029e6495594061945025/airflow/providers/google/cloud/example_dags/example_dataproc.py#L340-L346) for more details. You can view all possible parameters of `ClusterGenerator` in the [source code](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/623163f16ad2bbdd47d499e423fd5e37d36a028b/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/dataproc.py#L94-L165).