# Is it feasible to enable jupyterlab UI through DataprocClusterCreateOperator

Tags: python, airflow, google-cloud-dataproc

I see option as `enable_component_gateway` for Jupyterlabs through `gcloud`  command.
We are spinning cluster using DataprocClusterCreateOperator. I do not see any option in [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.3/_modules/airflow/contrib/operators/dataproc_operator.html#DataprocClusterCreateOperator) though which I can use to enable this feature during cluster creation.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this question was answered here: [Component Gateway with DataprocOperator on Airflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59568043/component-gateway-with-dataprocoperator-on-airflow) Please follow the steps from that question to enable component gateway during cluster creation operation.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31522710)