# Component Gateway activation on dataproc does not work with composer(airflow) operator airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.dataproc

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-dataproc, google-cloud-composer

I’m trying execute this dag bellow.
It seems that the operator creating a dataproc cluster does not enable enabling the optional components to enable jupyter notebook and anaconda.
I found this code here: [Component Gateway with DataprocOperator on Airflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59568043/component-gateway-with-dataprocoperator-on-airflow/71211981#71211981) to try to solve it, but for me it didn't solve it because i thikn the composer(airflow) version here is diferente. my version is composer - 2.0.0-preview.5, airflow-2.1.4.

The operator works perfectly when creating the cluster, but it doesn't create with the optional component to enable jupyter notebook.
Does anyone have any ideas to help me?

```
from airflow.contrib.sensors.gcs_sensor import GoogleCloudStoragePrefixSensor
from airflow import DAG
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.contrib.operators.dataproc_operator import DataprocClusterCreateOperator,DataprocClusterDeleteOperator, DataProcSparkOperator
from airflow.contrib.operators.gcs_to_bq import GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator

yesterday = datetime.combine(datetime.today() - timedelta(1),
                             datetime.min.time())


default_args = {
    'owner': 'teste3',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date' :yesterday,
    'email': ['airflow@example.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 0,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),

}

dag = DAG(
    'teste-dag-3',catchup=False, default_args=default_args, schedule_interval=None)


# configura os componentes
class CustomDataprocClusterCreateOperator(DataprocClusterCreateOperator):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomDataprocClusterCreateOperator, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def _build_cluster_data(self):
        cluster_data = super(CustomDataprocClusterCreateOperator, self)._build_cluster_data()
        cluster_data['config']['endpointConfig'] = {
            'enableHttpPortAccess': True
        }
        cluster_data['config']['softwareConfig']['optionalComponents'] = [ 'JUPYTER', 'ANACONDA' ]
        return cluster_data


create_cluster=CustomDataprocClusterCreateOperator(
        dag=dag,
        task_id='start_cluster_example',
        cluster_name='teste-ge-{{ ds }}',
        project_id= "sandbox-coe",
        num_workers=2,
        num_masters=1,
        master_machine_type='n2-standard-8',
        worker_machine_type='n2-standard-8',
        worker_disk_size=500,
        master_disk_size=500,
        master_disk_type='pd-ssd',
        worker_disk_type='pd-ssd',
        image_version='1.5.56-ubuntu18',
        tags=['allow-dataproc-internal'],
        region="us-central1",
        zone='us-central1-f',#Variable.get('gc_zone'),
        storage_bucket = "bucket-dataproc-ge",
        labels = {'product' : 'sample-label'},
        service_account_scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'],
        #properties={"yarn:yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb" : 15360,"yarn:yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb" : 15360},
        #subnetwork_uri="projects/project-id/regions/us-central1/subnetworks/dataproc-subnet",
        retries= 1,
        retry_delay=timedelta(minutes=1)
    ) #starts a dataproc cluster


stop_cluster_example = DataprocClusterDeleteOperator(
    dag=dag,
    task_id='stop_cluster_example',
    cluster_name='teste-ge-{{ ds }}',
    project_id="sandbox-coe",
    region="us-central1",
    ) #stops a running dataproc cluster




create_cluster  >> stop_cluster_example
```

Comment: Can you please be specific with what is not working? Do you get error?

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**
After took a deeper look you don't need a custom operator any more.
The updated operator `DataprocCreateClusterOperator` has `enable_component_gateway` and `optional_components` so you can just set them directly:

```
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.dataproc import ClusterGenerator, DataprocCreateClusterOperator

CLUSTER_GENERATOR = ClusterGenerator(
    project_id=PROJECT_ID,
    region=REGION,
    ...,
    enable_component_gateway=True,
    optional_components = [ 'JUPYTER', 'ANACONDA' ]
).make()

DataprocCreateClusterOperator(
    ...,
    cluster_config=CLUSTER_GENERATOR
)
```

You can check this [example dag](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/b2c0a921c155e82d1140029e6495594061945025/airflow/providers/google/cloud/example_dags/example_dataproc.py#L340-L346) for more details.
You can view all possible parameters of `ClusterGenerator` in the [source code](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/623163f16ad2bbdd47d499e423fd5e37d36a028b/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/dataproc.py#L94-L165).

**Original Answer:**
The operator was re-written (see [PR](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/6371)). I think the issue is with your `_build_cluster_data` function.

You probably should change your code to:

```
def _build_cluster_data(self):
    cluster_data = super(CustomDataprocClusterCreateOperator, self)._build_cluster_data()
    cluster_data['config']['endpoint_config'] = {
        'enableHttpPortAccess': True
    }
    cluster_data['config']['software_config']['optional_components'] = [ 'JUPYTER', 'ANACONDA' ] # redundant see comment 2
    return cluster_data
```

A few notes:

1. CustomDataprocClusterCreateOperator is deprecated. You should use `DataprocCreateClusterOperator` from the [google provider](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/index.html).
2. You don't need to have `cluster_data['config']['endpoint_config']` you can set the value directly by passing `optional_components` to the operator with see [source code](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/b2c0a921c155e82d1140029e6495594061945025/airflow/providers/google/cloud/example_dags/example_dataproc.py#L340-L346).

Comment: @ThiagoPositeliDeArruda Did it solve your issue? If so please accept the answer

Comment: Hi @Elad thanks for the help.
I Pass exactly like this right now 

but i got this error in airflow:

  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/baseoperator.py", line 178, in apply_defaults
    result = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/baseoperator.py", line 506, in __init__
    raise AirflowException(
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Invalid arguments were passed to DataprocCreateClusterOperator (task_id: start_cluster_example). Invalid arguments were:
**kwargs: {'enable_component_gateway': True}

Comment: i just set in operator directly

Comment: the same error in updated answer.
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/baseoperator.py", line 178, in apply_defaults
    result = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/baseoperator.py", line 506, in __init__
    raise AirflowException(
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Invalid arguments were passed to DataprocCreateClusterOperator (task_id: start_cluster_example). Invalid arguments were:
**kwargs: {'optional_components': ['JUPYTER', 'ANACONDA']}

Comment: when i remove "optional_components = [ 'JUPYTER', 'ANACONDA' ]" from operator, the dag run perfectly with the "enable_component_gateway=True", but when the cluster is created the interface web(component gateway) is disable

Comment: @ThiagoPositeliDeArruda sorry both are parameters of ClusterGenerator check now

Comment: some parts work like a charm. the cluster enable  this "optional_components = [ 'JUPYTER', 'ANACONDA' ]", but Web Interface to access jupyter notebook is disable. You no why?,  i set this in cluster config too "enable_component_gateway=True".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242280/discussion-between-thiago-positeli-de-arruda-and-elad).

Comment: If this wasn't resolved either there is a problem from your side or a bug in the operator. If its a bug then please open a GitHub issue: https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues

Comment: @ThiagoPositeliDeArruda, Could you please let me know if your issue is resolved or not?

Comment: Thanks @Elad I'm still researching to see if the problem is on my side or it's a bug, but I believe my code is correct, because it creates and deletes the cluster normally and with the latest tweaks you suggested it enabled additional components like jupyter and anaconda, but did not activate the web interface, even setting the property to True

Comment: @PrajnaRaiT its not resolved completely. 
i put this "optional_components = [ 'JUPYTER', 'ANACONDA' ]" in cluster_generator as in the solution above and the web interface in cluster dataproc still disable.

Comment: Sorry but I don't think there is more we can do here. It's either bug in your settings or bug in the open source (Airflow or google python package). Both cases are out of scope for StackOverflow.

Comment: @ThiagoPositeliDeArruda, I have also tried to enable component gateway to access web interfaces, by including enable_component_gateway=True along with optional_components=['JUPYTER', 'ANACONDA'] in the code. Still the component gateway was in the disabled state. Also, I found the Github issue you had raised. Posting the [issue link](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/21800) here for posterity.

Comment: Yeah this seems to be a bug in Airflow.

Comment: yeah, i posted this issue @PrajnaRaiT.

Comment: The bug has been fixed and now working in the new airflow updated 2.2.3 and composer version 2.0.5.

Comment: If so then this was probably a bug in composer rather than Airflow as we didn't release new Airflow version...

Comment: @Elad i think u are right. Much thanks for the help and the solution u give me.

Comment: If solved then kindly accept the answer as it is the solution after composer fixed whatever bug they had on thier side.

Comment: If you somehow don't want to use ClusterGenerator class and would like to directly type into cluster_config dict, add `"endpoint_config": {"enable_http_port_access": True` instead. (See the [source code](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_modules/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/dataproc.html#ClusterGenerator.make) for the implementation of ClusterGenerator.)